# How to implement "if else if else" condition in XSLT

Tags: xslt

Is it possible to implement "if else, if else" in xsl? for example I have data:

```
<document>
    <line>
        <name>MAR111</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </line>

    <line>
        <name>MAR111</name>
        <value>3</value>
    </line>
    <line>
        <name>MEA111</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </line>
    <line>
        <name>MPR111</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </line>
    <line>
        <name>MEA111</name>
        <value>4</value>
    </line>
    <line>
        <name>MPR111</name>
        <value>2</value>
    </line>
</document>
```

I need to get three document templates with three names:

```
<document>
    <MAR>
        <name>MAR111</name>
        <number>1</number>
        <number>4</number>
    </MAR>
</document>
<document>
    <MEA>
        <name>MEA111</name>
        <number>1</number>
        <number>4</number>
    </MEA>
</document>
<document>
    <MPR>
        <name>MPR111</name>
        <number>1</number>
        <number>2</number>
    </MPR>
</document>
```

I try to use "choose, when" on apply template, but maybe there is a better way:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="/document/line/name='MEA111'">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="MEA" select="/document"/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="/document/line/name='MPR111'">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="MPR" select="/document"/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="/document/line/name='MAR111'">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="MAR" select="/document"/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Check my answer for the correct XSLT way for doing this.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Actually you can merge them together:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="/document/line/name='MEA111'">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="MEA" select="/document"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="/document/line/name='MPR111'">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="MPR" select="/document"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="/document/line/name='MAR111'">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="MAR" select="/document"/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

EDIT: Petras, after your clarification, it seems that what you want is even easier:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:if test="/document/line/name='MEA111'">
       <xsl:apply-templates mode="MEA" select="/document"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="/document/line/name='MPR111'">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="MPR" select="/document"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="/document/line/name='MAR111'">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="MAR" select="/document"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: But when we will get only one result of first condition which will be true. I need to get three result because all condition is correct

Answer (score 6):

The best way is to use separate templates.

```
<xsl:template match="/document/line/name='MEA111'">
       <xsl:apply-templates mode="MEA" select="/document"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/document/line/name='MPR111'">
       <xsl:apply-templates mode="MPR" select="/document"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/document/line/name='MAR111'">
       <xsl:apply-templates mode="MAR" select="/document"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Even less lines and this is more maintainable.

Answer (score 5):

No, `choose when` is the xsl way of saying `if else`. No better way

Answer (score 2):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kLineByName" match="line" use="name"/>
    <xsl:template match="line[count(.|key('kLineByName',name)[1]) = 1]">
        <document>
            <xsl:element name="{substring(name,1,3)}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="name|key('kLineByName',name)/value"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </document>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<document>
    <MAR>
        <name>MAR111</name>
        <value>1</value>
        <value>3</value>
    </MAR>
</document>
<document>
    <MEA>
        <name>MEA111</name>
        <value>1</value>
        <value>4</value>
    </MEA>
</document>
<document>
    <MPR>
        <name>MPR111</name>
        <value>1</value>
        <value>2</value>
    </MPR>
</document>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to implement a catch-all fall through (e.g. equivalent to "else"), you should use [`otherwise`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_otherwise.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="name() = 'MAR111'">
    ... do something ...
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    ... do something as fallback ...
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

BR Markus

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can achieve things using `<xsl:choose><xsl:when>` but if, else if, condition is also supported in @select attribute of different xslt construct for example :

```
<xsl:value-of select="if (@geography = 'North America') then 
                 'Domestic car'
                else if (@geography = 'Europe') then 
                  'Import from Europe'
                else if (@geography = 'Asia') then 
                  &quot;It's from Asia&quot;
                (: If it's anything else :)
                else 
                   'We don''t know!'"/>
```

Comment: Requires XSLT 2.0.