# How to change XML from dataset into HTML UL

Tags: c#, html, xml, xslt

I'm working on a C# webforms application and have a datalayer which gathers information about the menu a customer can see, based on their customer number and order type.

I was using the ASP.NET menu control for this until the qa department asked to change the menu to expand on click instead of hover.  At that point, I decided to try and do the menu with a simpler css/html/jquery approach but I've hit a jam.

I have the following method in my datalayer that gets information for the menu and returns it as XML.  What I'm stuck on is how to take the XML that was being gathered, when I was using the menu control and hopefully reformat it into a UL for using in the html/css approach I'd like to do.

```
public static string BuildMenu(string cprcstnm, string docType)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DynamicsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            string sql = "usp_SelectItemMenuByCustomer";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@CPRCSTNM", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cprcstnm;
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@DOCID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = docType;
            da.Fill(ds);
            da.Dispose();
        }
        ds.DataSetName = "Menus";
        ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Menu";
        DataRelation relation = new DataRelation("ParentChild",
                                                 ds.Tables["Menu"].Columns["MenuID"],
                                                 ds.Tables["Menu"].Columns["ParentID"],
                                                 false);

        relation.Nested = true;
        ds.Relations.Add(relation);

        return ds.GetXml();
    }
```

A sample of XMl that is output is as follows:

```
<Menus>
- <Menu>
  <MenuID>23</MenuID> 
  <ITEMNMBR>0</ITEMNMBR> 
  <Text>ACC</Text> 
  <Description>ACC</Description> 
  <ParentID>0</ParentID> 
- <Menu>
  <MenuID>34</MenuID> 
  <ITEMNMBR>1</ITEMNMBR> 
  <Text>BASE</Text> 
  <Description>BASE</Description> 
  <ParentID>23</ParentID> 
- <Menu>
  <MenuID>516</MenuID> 
  <ITEMNMBR>2</ITEMNMBR> 
  <Text>HYP</Text> 
  <Description>HYP</Description> 
  <ParentID>34</ParentID>
```

I would need to convert this to something such as :

```
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#">ACC</a>
        <ul class="sub_menu">
           <li>
          <a href="#">BASE</a>
              <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">HYP</a>
              <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Terminal 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Terminal 1</a></li>
               </ul>    
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: I have looked at it but I'm not sure I can it to nest the menus like I need too.  The menu levels will vary.  I've never used XSLT before so I fully admit ignorance on the subject though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get some ideas from the following MSDN link that illustrates writing html from a dataset using xslt

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fd7xytc(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: This sounds promising but I would need to conditionally build nested levels in the menu.  XSLT seems more of a straight one to one mapping of items.   With the data I'm stuck with, I will have to conditionally do things like change the href to a redirect if I have an item number otherwise, leave it as a "#" for the href value.  I've no idea if that's possible in XSLT.

Comment: conditional XSLT can be written. once you get hang of it, it can be fun. check the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169140/how-to-implement-if-else-if-else-condition-in-xslt

Comment: This is the road I'm heading down and it looks like it will work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic way to do it.Or some kind of GUI tool to make it for you.

You will have to manipulate your XML and convert it into equivalent( according to your need) html.

- First I would suggest you, that if only you wanted to handle the click effect of `MenuItems` and CSS related issues, don't change it. you can very easily bind a jQuery function to your `ASP Menu` items. 
  You can do so,  very easily .Just add a `css class` to your `asp:menuItem` and grab it using jQuery like this:

  ```
  <asp:Menu ID="myMenu" runat="server">
  ..
  <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="" CssClass="menuItem" Text="Menu1" Value="Menu1"/>
  ```

  and grab it like

  ```
    $('.menuItem').click(function(){
           $(this).css({'width':'100px'});
    });
  ```
- And if you are seriously to throw away your ASP Menu Control, but not the XML datasource for `menus`, then get ready for some serious string manipulation. do it like this.

  ```
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(xml);
  XmlNodeList menus = doc.SelectNodes("//Menus/Menu");

  string html ="<ul>";
  foreach(XmlNode menu in menus)
  {
     html += "<li><a href='#' >";
     html += menu.SelectSingleNode("Text").InnerText + "</a></li>";
  }
  html +="</ul>";
  ```

Comment: I think I may be stuck with the string building route in all honesty.  That's a bummer but I just think I'm stuck.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: you can build your string, you can also append css classes to them, and write those css classes in stylesheet included in the aspx page. there's no problem in that, prblm is, if your xml structure changes, it will cause a ripple effect on ur string building logic. besides, you can accept it as an answer, if it helped you.:)